# How to parse verb + participle structure

Tags: participle-phrases, secondary-predicates

I would like to ask how to parse the following sentence.

> I cook listening to music.

"I" is subject.
"cook" is the main verb

Is "listening to music" is participle phrase? 
( to music is also preposition phrase)

Does " listening" modify "I" so is it adjective or does it modify "cook" ?

Comment: *Listening to music* is an adjectival participle phrase acting as a 'secondary predicate'; see questions with the tag [tag:secondary-predicates].

Comment: It sounds as if "listening to music" is a special dish. I'd rephrase it to I cook and listen to music. or While I am listening to music I cook.

Comment: Yes, "I" is the subject and "to music" is a preposition phrase as complement of "listening". "Listening to music" is a gerund-participial clause modifying the matrix (main) verb phrase "cook". Functionally, "listening to music" can plausibly be analysed as a temporal adjunct, cf "I cook while I'm listening to music".

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence, "while" is elided:  "I cook *while* listening to music", which can be restructured as "while/when cooking, I listen to music" or "while/when I cook, I listen to music".

The restructuring "while/when listening to music, I cook" doesn't work very well since it implies that I cook whenever I listen to music.  The "while/when" has to remain attached to "cook" if the meaning is to remain the same.

So it seems to me that "listening to music" is an *adverbial* phrase, since it expands (modifies, tells us more about) the verb "cook".  It's also a participial phrase, but that seems inevitable (or at least I can't offhand think of a construction that wouldn't have a participle).